# Анимация usingSpringWithDamping Xib файла

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

Не обходимо по нажатию на кнопку показывать всплывающий алерт(xib) с анимацией usingSpringWithDamping. Не могу разобраться как реализовать. Мой вариант не работает, алерт появляется без анимации

```
var startLevelSubview: StartLevel!
@IBAction func levelSelected(sender: AnyObject) {

if(startLevelSubview != nil && !startLevelSubview.view.isHidden) {
    startLevelSubview.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
startLevelSubview = StartLevel(frame: CGRect  (x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 320))
startLevelSubview.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y)

startLevelSubview.levelLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Level \(sender.tag!)", comment:"")

let targetImage = UIImage(named: "LevelButtonBg.png")
startLevelSubview.firstTargetImage.image = targetImage

self.view.addSubview(startLevelSubview)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    self.startLevelSubview?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
}, completion: nil)
}
```

А добавляя во viewDidLoad следующую строку происходит крэш fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
startLevelSubview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View` и так уже имеет scale = 1. Чтобы была анимация с затуханием при создании задайте view фрейм поменьше:

```
startLevelSubview = StartLevel(frame: CGRect(origin: view.center, size: CGSize.zero))
```

И затем анимируете до нужного размера:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .layoutSubviews, animations: {
    startLevelSubview.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 320)
    startLevelSubview.center = self.view.center
}, completion: nil)
```

Повторно задаем центр в таком варианте, т.к. до этого центр у Вас был задан для вью с нулевым размером.